# Unable to change the permission of a file using chmod

Tags: command-line, chmod

The command `chmod -x filename` doesn't work for me.

When I execute the command like this:

```
chmod -r filename
chmod -w filename
chmod -x filename
```

They complete without any error. But the permission of the files doesn't get affected.

Comment: Is your file on ntfs partition ?

Comment: We need more information. Most common a NTFS or FAT partition, but there can be other reasons. File systems can be mounted noexec for example. What file, what file system, and what mount options?

Comment: You've not specified a user target and: `If none of these are given, the effect is as if a were given, but bits that are set in the umask are not affected.` (man chmod). Try `chmod u+x filename` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing `-` with `+`. One adds a permission, the other removes it. Here's a silly little test with a new file that starts with global `rwx` (aka 0777):

```
$ install -m 777 <(echo) test; ls -l test
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oli oli 1 Oct  3 13:34 test
```

Let's *remove* read permissions with `-r`:

```
$ chmod -r test; ls -l test
--wx-wx-wx 1 oli oli 1 Oct  3 13:34 test
```

And add them back with `+r`:

```
$ chmod +r test; ls -l test
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oli oli 1 Oct  3 13:34 test
```

Answer (score -1):

Try executing your commands in `sudo` mode.

```
sudo chmod -r /path/to/file/filename
sudo chmod -w /path/to/file/filename
sudo chmod -x /path/to/file/filename
```

And make sure the account you are using has the right permissions to change those properties.

Comment: The command would fail if `sudo` was needed.

Comment: You are wrong. I had several times that I didn't got any error without using `sudo`

Comment: This answer is probably best posted as a comment as we do not have sufficient information to answer the question yet.

Comment: `laurent@Hoedic-U14:~$ chmod u+w /etc/wgetrc 
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/etc/wgetrc’: Operation not permitted`